# JavaScript div same name input serialization to json array

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

I have the following html :

```
<div id="formdata">

<input type='hidden' name='item_name' value='1001-UMBRELLA'/>
<input type='hidden' name='item_name' value='1002-UMBRELLA'/>
<input type='hidden' name='item_name' value='1003-UMBRELLA'/>

<input type='hidden' name='rate' value='20.00'/>
<input type='hidden' name='rate' value='40.00'/>
<input type='hidden' name='rate' value='60.00'/>

<input type='hidden' name='quantity' value='10.00'/>
<input type='hidden' name='quantity' value='20.00'/>    
<input type='hidden' name='quantity' value='30.00'/>

</div>
```

What I am tying to get in JSON form is :

```
[{'item_name':'1001-UMBRELLA', 'quantity':'10', 'rate':'20'}, 
{'item_name':'1002-UMBRELLA', 'quantity':'20', 'rate':'40'},
{'item_name':'1003-UMBRELLA', 'quantity':'30', 'rate':'60'}]
```

I have tried the .serializeArray() which gives output in name value pair, renders the following output :

```
[{'name':'item_name','value':'1001-UMBRELLA'},{'name':'item_name','value':'1002-UMBRELLA'},{'name':'item_name','value':'1003-UMBRELLA'},{'name':'rate','value':'20.00'},{'name':'rate','value':'40.00'},{'name':'rate','value':'60.00'},{'name':'quantity','value':'10.00'},{'name':'quantity','value':'20.00'},{'name':'quantity','value':'30.00'}]
```

Will this be better achieved with data model binding ?

Answer (score 1):

According to the structure of your input elements you may use [.map()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) plus [.querySelectorAll()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelectorAll)

```js
var retVal = Array.from(document.querySelectorAll("#formdata input[name='item_name']")).map(function(ele) {
    var x = {};
    x[ele.name] = ele.value;
    x[ele.nextElementSibling.name] = Number(ele.nextElementSibling.value).toString();
    x[ele.nextElementSibling.nextElementSibling.name] = Number(ele.nextElementSibling.nextElementSibling.value).toString();
    return x;
});

console.log(retVal);
```

```html
<div id="formdata">
    <input type='hidden' name='item_name' value='1001-UMBRELLA'/>
    <input type='hidden' name='quantity' value='10.00'/>
    <input type='hidden' name='rate' value='20.00'/>

    <input type='hidden' name='item_name' value='1002-UMBRELLA'/>
    <input type='hidden' name='quantity' value='20.00'/>
    <input type='hidden' name='rate' value='40.00'/>

    <input type='hidden' name='item_name' value='1002-UMBRELLA'/>
    <input type='hidden' name='quantity' value='30.00'/>
    <input type='hidden' name='rate' value='60.00'/>
</div>
```

Comment: What if the siblings change in order?

Comment: @NitinKabra Yes, you are right. Indeed my answer is related to the current order. Without a specific order/condition it's required a logic depending on your goal: how the inputs are ordered, what if an attribute is missing and so on...

Comment: Output should be `'quantity':'10', 'rate':'20'`, not `'quantity':'10.00', 'rate':'20.00'`.

Comment: It's not an integer. It's a stringed number with no trailing decimal place.

Comment: :) No, the OP's required output: `rate: "20"` not `rate: 20`.

Comment: @Andy ...and now? Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Here you go. This will work regardless of the order of the input fields.

```js
var serializeGroup = function(formId) {
  var items = $('input[name]', formId).serializeArray();

  // Groups the element array by the `name` attribute
  var group = items.reduce((seed, item) => {
    (seed[item.name] = seed[item.name] || []).push(item);
    return seed;
  }, {});

  // Iterates through the grouped names
  return Object
    .keys(group)
    .map((name, index, all) =>
      // Flattens the list into a key-value pair
      all.reduce((seed, key) => {
        var value = group[key][index].value;

        seed[key] = $.isNumeric(value) ? Math.round(value) : value;

        return seed;
      }, {})
    );
}

let data = serializeGroup('#formdata');

console.log(data);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div id="formdata">
  <input type='hidden' name='item_name' value='1003-UMBRELLA' />
  <input type='hidden' name='quantity' value='30.00' />
  <input type='hidden' name='item_name' value='1001-UMBRELLA' />
  <input type='hidden' name='quantity' value='10.00' />
  <input type='hidden' name='rate' value='60.00' />
  <input type='hidden' name='item_name' value='1002-UMBRELLA' />
  <input type='hidden' name='rate' value='20.00' />
  <input type='hidden' name='rate' value='40.00' />
  <input type='hidden' name='quantity' value='20.00' />
</div>
```

Comment: Output should be `'quantity':'10', 'rate':'20'`, not `'quantity':'10.00', 'rate':'20.00'`.

Comment: Yeah I noticed that, posting a fix in a min.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a recursive vanilla JS example that matches your output. It doesn't assume the inputs are in the right order, the grouping can be any number, and it formats the quantity and rate correctly.

```js
// Create an array from the inputs
const inputs = Array.from(document.querySelectorAll('#formdata input'));

function serialiseInputs(tail, grouping, out) {

  // Set the output array to a new array if it doesn't exist
  out = out || [];

  // If the length of the tail array (remaining inputs) is 0
  // return the output array
  if (!tail.length) return out;

  // Grab the number of inputs that satisfies the grouping number
  const head = tail.splice(0, grouping);

  // `reduce` over the head creating the new object, and add it to the
  // output array
  out.push(head.reduce((acc, { name, value}) => {
    if (['rate', 'quantity'].includes(name)) value = (+value).toString();
    acc[name] = value;
    return acc;
  }, {}));

  // Call the function again with the remaining inputs
  return serialiseInputs(tail, grouping, out);
}

// Call the function with the inputs, and the grouping number
console.log(serialiseInputs(inputs, 4));
```

```html
<div id="formdata">
  <input type='hidden' name='temp' value='temp1'/>
  <input type='hidden' name='quantity' value='10.00'/>
  <input type='hidden' name='rate' value='20.00'/>
  <input type='hidden' name='item_name' value='1001-UMBRELLA'/>

  <input type='hidden' name='quantity' value='20.00'/>
  <input type='hidden' name='temp' value='temp2'/>
  <input type='hidden' name='item_name' value='1002-UMBRELLA'/>
  <input type='hidden' name='rate' value='40.00'/>

  <input type='hidden' name='rate' value='60.00'/>
  <input type='hidden' name='item_name' value='1002-UMBRELLA'/>
  <input type='hidden' name='quantity' value='30.00'/>
  <input type='hidden' name='temp' value='temp3'/>
</div>
```

Comment: There could be more elements, which will require the array definition code update. @gaetanoM's solution solves that issue. But the order need to be maintained in that solution too.

Comment: @NitinKabra, the answers are based on the details in your question. If you don't state that the order might be out of sequence why should we make that assumption?

Comment: Anyway, I've updated my code to give you the output you need regardless of the order.

Answer (score 0):

```js
function GetArray() {
    var arry = [];
    var item = {};
    var fisrtProeprty;
    $.each($("input[type=hidden]"), function (index, value) {

        var name = $(value).attr("name");
        var value = $(value).attr("value");
        if (index === 0) {
            fisrtProeprty = name;
        }
        if (fisrtProeprty == name && index > 0) {
            arry.push(item);
            item = {};

        }
        if (!item[name]) {
            item[name] = value;
        }

    });
    arry.push(item);
    return arry;
}
var myArray = GetArray();
console.log(myArray);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="formdata">
  <input type='hidden' name='item_name' value='1001-UMBRELLA'/>
  <input type='hidden' name='quantity' value='10.00'/>
  <input type='hidden' name='rate' value='20.00'/>
  <input type='hidden' name='fatih' value='100'/>

  <input type='hidden' name='item_name' value='1002-UMBRELLA'/>
  <input type='hidden' name='quantity' value='20.00'/>
  <input type='hidden' name='rate' value='40.00'/>
  <input type='hidden' name='fatih' value='258'/>

  <input type='hidden' name='item_name' value='1002-UMBRELLA'/>
  <input type='hidden' name='quantity' value='30.00'/>
  <input type='hidden' name='rate' value='60.00'/>
  <input type='hidden' name='fatih' value='145'/>
</div>
```

Comment: result is unexpected if the order changes.

Comment: @NitinKabra yes but this question is also important

Comment: Output should be `'quantity':'10', 'rate':'20'`, not `'quantity':'10.00', 'rate':'20.00'`.